# php - Increment an arrays second value if the first value has a matching string

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, string, if-statement

I am working on a WordPress widget to output a table for a specific post type (Projects) with the types 2 required fields. The data received is "location" and "power". I want to add a feature that adds up all "power" variables, which are formatted as numbers, if the "location" has already been created.

For example, if 3 different Projects posts create:

`"location"=> Winnipeg, MB "power"=>2,
"location"=> Winnipeg, MB "power"=>5,
"location"=> Saskatchewan, AB "power"=>2`

Then I want the output to be:

`"location"=> Winnipeg, MB "power"=>7,
"location"=> Saskatchewan, AB "power"=>2`

My code:

```
<?php
$all_locations=array();
$all_projects=array();
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
  $the_query->the_post();
  global $post;
  $id = $post->ID;
  $project_location = get_field('location');
  $single_kilowatts = get_field('kilowatts');
  $single_location = $project_location['address'];
  array_push($all_locations, $single_location);
  $project_entry=array(
    $single_location,
    $single_kilowatts 
  );
    $project_entry = compact('single_location','single_power');
    array_push($all_projects, $project_entry);
endwhile;
$unique = array_unique($all_locations);
print_r($unique);
print_r($all_projects);
?>
```

So far this all works, and the 2 last lines will print:

```
Array ( [0] => Winnipeg, MB [1] => Saskatchewan, AB)
Array ( [0] => Array ( [single_location] => Winnipeg, MB [total_kW] => 2 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [single_location] => Winnipeg, MB [total_kW] => 5 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [single_location] => Saskatchewan, AB [total_kW] => 2 ) )
```

After this, I am completely lost and don't know how to output the data in the way I mentioned at the beginning. Should I start a new while loop or use foreach? How can I most efficiently structure my if statement? 


If you have any answers or some tips on my syntax please let me know. I am a junior developer, with little understanding of php and am very happy to hear any tips or tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below code:

```
$all_projects=array();
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    $the_query->the_post();
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $project_location = get_field('location');
    $single_kilowatts = get_field('kilowatts');
    $single_location = $project_location['address'];

    $all_projects[$project_location['address']] = (isset($all_projects[$project_location['address']]))?$all_projects[$project_location['address']] + $single_kilowatts : $single_kilowatts;

endwhile;
$unique = array_keys($all_projects);;
print_r($unique);
print_r($all_projects);
```